# Uploading an image to a post renders (incorrectly) nested square brackets in markdown

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, images

I just asked a new question here on meta, and when I added a screen capture I noticed an out-of-place dotted line beneath my image.

Checking the markdown, I see this:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lezK.png
```

Should there be a second set of brackets and a duplicate `[1]` in the markdown?

Or should the markdown look like this, which also renders the image correctly:

```
![enter image description here][1]
```

I see the same behavior on the main SO site too.

Also, using Chrome v49.0.2623.87 (64-bit).

Comment: Yes, I'm also seeing that all the time. Especially if I edit to make images posted by < 10 rep users visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a fairly recent change - the idea is that large images were difficult for people to link correctly.

So we do that by default for images - they are clickable and link directly to the image itself.